# It is possible to use parallel compression method in lxc publish?

Tags: lxc, lxd

To generate images LXD compresses files using `gzip`, which can only use one core. Thus, creating images can be very slow with large containers. I would like to use other compressors (e.g., `pigz`). What options I have to speed up the creation of images? A similar question was discused in [this mailing list](https://lxc-users.linuxcontainers.narkive.com/yVeaGgge/lxc-publish-how-to-use-pigz-parallel-gzip-for-compression). However, that discussion was two years ago. Maybe, the status have changed.

I imagine using something like:

```
$ lxc publish $container --alias $container --compression pigz
```

If parallel compressors are not available, is it possible to specify the compression level?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You say "file**s**". It is possible to compress files in parallel, using a non-parallel compressor. But this will require modifying the code that calls the compressor (does it have an option to do this already?).

Using a parallel compressor for each file, may be possible, but compression ratios will be reduced. e.g. independently compressing the two halves. But then if the two halves are the same, the compressor will not see it, and compression will be lost.

If `lxc publish` is compressing across files (for more compression), then even the first option will reduce compression, for the same reason outlined in the 2nd paragraph.

---

Edit:

Having said that I just looked at some benchmarks for `pigz`. I think using the default over-lapping blocks (I have now read the manual), and they are no worse than `gzip`.

Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Yes, it works. Using pigz makes a big difference in multicore machines.

Comment: What did you do to get it to work? While I though that this may be the best answer that you would get. I did not expect it to be excepted. Can you add an answer to tell us what you did to get it to work. When have written an answer that explains how to get it working, comment to me, and I will up-vote.

Comment: you are right, the answer is not completely clear. Also, I make a mistake because I only check that `lxc export --compression pigz $container $container` works. Thus, I have not checked what happens with `publish`. I am going to review if it also works.

Comment: @DanielHernández `lxc publish $container --compression pigz` works great as well.